# OpenGL Image Load/Store 24-bit RGB images

Tags: opengl, textures, rgb, opengl-4, image-unit

It looks like glBindImageTexture does not have an [image format](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml) for 24-bit RGB (3 8-bit channels) images. My texture has an internal format of the type `GL_RGB8` (a 24-bit RGB image). Unfortunately I cannot easily change the type of my texture that I'm binding to the image unit at runtime -- is it possible to use a different image format with imageLoad and still access the 24-bit RGB data?

Comment: "*Unfortunately I cannot easily change the type of my texture that I'm binding to the image unit at runtime*" ... how not? It's *your texture*; you created it. How can you not be in control of its format?

Comment: While I can change the format of the texture, I cannot actually change the pixel data at runtime. In other words, I get an byte array of a certain size that's internally structured with 3 consecutive 8-bit fields -- I can't create a new array that has 4 consecutive 8-bit fields so that I could use GL_RGBA8UI

Comment: ... So? OpenGL can upload RGB data to an RGBA8 texture. And if you think that this will be slower, consider that OpenGL is probably *already doing that* with your current 3-channel texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use GL_RGB8 with image load/store. This is done because implementations are allowed to support `GL_RGB8` by substituting it with `GL_RGBA8`. But they are also allowed to not do that if they can support 3-component formats directly. So OpenGL as a specification does not know if the implementation can actually handle 24-bits-per-pixel or if its pretending to do so with a 32-bit texture.

So OpenGL just forces *you* to do the substitution explicitly.